# Hibernate populate only one table

Tags: java, database, hibernate, pojo

in my project I'm mapping the DB to the class using xml(not Annotations), I have mapped two tables to one class as follow.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.fg.fixtransbridge.model.BookStatistics"
    entity-name="BookStatistics" table="book_statistics">       
  </class>

  <class name="com.fg.fixtransbridge.model.BookStatistics"
    entity-name="BookStatisticsHistory" table="book_statistics_copy">
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And when I tries to add data to the two tables at once, only the **book_statistics** table gets filled. It's because I called it 1st

> ***b*** is a BookStatistics instansce and it's filled with data

```
    session.saveOrUpdate("BookStatistics", b);
    session.saveOrUpdate("BookStatisticsHistory", b);
```

If i calls  **session.saveOrUpdate("BookStatisticsHistory", b)**  1st, then only the other table get filled.

```
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate("BookStatistics", b);
    session.saveOrUpdate("BookStatisticsHistory", b);     
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

So is there any way to fill those two tables using  single service. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is b ? a BookStatistics or BookStatisticsHistory, I assume it is BookStatistics instance , I-m rigth

Comment: sorry, yeh. it's a BookStatistics instance. there is no BookStatisticsHistory class anyway

Comment: @Koitoer u have any answer?? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using two sessions. like,

```
Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

But I think this is not very good practice. Anyway there is no need of a two tables in one DAO. That too isn't a good practise.

> So I've created two DAOs for the two tables and did my **CRUD (Create,
>   Read, Update, Delete)** operations there and used one service to call
>   booth.

And for the sake of effectiveness, I ***Autowired*** the session factory. Otherwise when it tries to do any CRUD operations, It creates a new session factory every time which consumes a lot of time and resource.